# Rails date i18n with custom formats not translating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-i18n

I made an initializer named: 'date_formats.rb' and it looks like:

```
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%B %e, %Y" # November 3, 2013
DateTime::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%B %e, %Y" # November 3, 2013 14:22
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%B %d, %Y %H:%M"           # November 3, 2013 14:22
```

So when i call `somemodel.created_at` i got something like: `December 16, 2014 12:37`. I love this because i dont have to struggle with `strftime` anymore

The problem begins when i need this date to print in spanish. So far i have installed **rails-18n** gem, and because i have to translate some custom texts i have already an **es.yml** that looks like this:

```
es:
  hello: "Hello world"
  Client: "Cliente"
  update: "Actualización"
  create: "Creación"
  identification_number: "Número de identificación"
  created_by: "Creado por"
  identification_type: "Tipo de identificación"
  name: "Nombre"
  observations: "Observaciones"
  status: "Estado"
  client_type: "Tipo de cliente"
  contract_start_date: "Fecha de inicio de contrato"
  contract_end_date: "Fecha de fin de contrato"
  contact_name: "Nombre del contacto"
  telephone: "Teléfono"
  email: "Email"
  address: "Dirección"
  created_by_id: "Id creador"
  date:
    order:
      - :day
      - :month
      - :year
    abbr_day_names:
      - dom
      - lun
      - mar
      - mié
      - jue
      - vie
      - sáb
    abbr_month_names:
      - ~
      - ene
      - feb
      - mar
      - abr
      - may
      - jun
      - jul
      - ago
      - sep
      - oct
      - nov
      - dic
    day_names:
      - domingo
      - lunes
      - martes
      - miércoles
      - jueves
      - viernes
      - sábado
    month_names:
      - ~
      - enero
      - febrero
      - marzo
      - abril
      - mayo
      - junio
      - julio
      - agosto
      - septiembre
      - octubre
      - noviembre
      - diciembre
    formats:
      short: "%d de %b"
      default: "%d/%m/%Y"
      long: "%A, %d de %B de %Y"
  time:
    formats:
      short: "%d de %b a las %H:%M hrs"
      default: "%a, %d de %b de %Y a las %H:%M:%S %Z"
      long: "%A, %d de %B de %Y a las %I:%M %p"
    am: "am"
    pm: "pm"
```

It doesnt translate my dates. It only works if i call it like this `l somemodel.created_at` but i dont want to call the method localize everytime i need to display a date.

So far my **application.rb** looks like this:

```
config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '**', '*.{rb,yml}')]
config.i18n.available_locales = ['es', :es]
config.i18n.default_locale = :es
I18n.locale = config.i18n.locale = config.i18n.default_locale
```

Note that i have tried a lot of workarounds to be sure it is loading the correct .yml, and i have made sure it is.

Answer (score 1):

But the `localize` or short `l` method is the method that does the trick. You cannot get rid of it. Without that method the `I18n` module is not called at all.

Comment: got it.. anyways it must be a way to translate the dates automatically.

Comment: You could override `to_s` on `Date` and `DateTime` to always use `I18n`. but I think that is a terrible idea and surprising solution for such a simple usecase. Remember Rails 2.3? You had to add `h` to everything in a view, now it is only `l` to things you what to localize.

Comment: why do you think this is terrible idea? i find it interesting

Comment: Overriding core methods (like `Date#to_s`) will bite you later on. Because all other libraries and parts of the system will also not use the orginal implementation but your overriden version. Can you be sure that all other libraries can handle the change format? E.g. database drivers writing timestamps, cookies liftime management, scheduled background job processing?